# MySQL (MariaDB - 10.0.16-MariaDB-1 (Debian) strange performance issues

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, database-performance, mariadb

I am running version 10.0.16-MariaDB-1 (Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)) on Dual Xeon CPU, total 32 cores with 128 GB of RAM. This is a dedicated DB server and has been recently migrated over from Percona DB server. My configuration looks like this,

```
################################################################################
# DATE: 19-01-2014
# DESCRIPTION: MySQL config
# RAM: 128GB RAM dedicated server
# Connections: 1000 connections
################################################################################

[mysql]
# CLIENT #
port                           = 1979
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]

## Files
back_log            = 300
open-files-limit        = 8192
#open-files             = 1024  

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
port                           = 1979
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

## Per-Thread Buffers * (max_connections) = total per-thread mem usage
thread_stack            = 512K    #default: 32bit: 192K, 64bit: 256K
sort_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 2M, larger may cause perf issues
read_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 128K, change in increments of 4K
read_rnd_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 256K                
join_buffer_size        = 2M      #default: 128K
binlog_cache_size       = 128K    #default: 32K, size of buffer to hold TX queries
## total per-thread buffer memory usage: 17664000K = 17.250GB

## Query Cache
query_cache_size        = 64M   #global buffer
query_cache_limit               = 2M    #max query result size to put in cache

## Connections
max_connections = 900   #multiplier for memory usage via per-thread buffers
max_connect_errors      = 1000  #default: 10
concurrent_insert = 2
connect_timeout         = 10    #default -5.1.22: 5, +5.1.22: 10
max_allowed_packet      = 32M   #max size of incoming data to allow

## Default Table Settings
sql_mode            = NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER

## Table and TMP settings
max_heap_table_size         = 1G    #recommend same size as tmp_table_size
bulk_insert_buffer_size         = 1G    #recommend same size as tmp_table_size
tmp_table_size                  = 1G    #recommend 1G min
tmpdir                         = /dev/shm        #Recommend using RAMDISK for tmpdir

## Table cache settings
#table_cache            = 512   #5.0.x <default: 64>
#table_open_cache       = 512   #5.1.x, 5.5.x <default: 64>

query-cache-type = 1

## Thread settings
thread_concurrency      = 32  #recommend 2x CPU cores
thread_cache_size       = 400 #recommend 5% of max_connections

## InnoDB Plugin Independent Settings
innodb_data_home_dir            = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_data_file_path       = ibdata1:128M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_file_size        = 768M  #64G_RAM+ = 768, 24G_RAM+ = 512, 8G_RAM+ = 256, 2G_RAM+ = 128 
innodb_log_files_in_group   = 4 #combined size of all logs <4GB. <2G_RAM = 2, >2G_RAM = 4
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 96G   #global buffer
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M    #global buffer
innodb_status_file          #extra reporting
innodb_file_per_table           #enable always
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_table_locks      = 0 #preserve table locks
innodb_log_buffer_size      = 128M  #global buffer
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600
#innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_commit_concurrency = 8   #recommend 4x num disks
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC    #O_DIRECT = local/DAS, O_DSYNC = SAN/iSCSI
innodb_support_xa       = 0        #recommend 0, disable xa to negate extra disk flush
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
skip-innodb-doublewrite
skip-host-cache
# skip-name-resolve

## Binlog sync settings
## XA transactions = 1, otherwise set to 0 for best performance
sync_binlog         = 0

## TX Isolation
#transaction-isolation      = REPEATABLE-READ #REPEATABLE-READ req for ACID, SERIALIZABLE req XA

## Per-Thread Buffer memory utilization equation:
#(read_buffer_size + read_rnd_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size + thread_stack + join_buffer_size + binlog_cache_size) * max_connections

## Replication
#server_id           = 1
#log_bin             = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
#log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log.index
#relay_log           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin
#relay_log_index     = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.index
#expire_logs_days    = 10
#max_binlog_size     = 100M
#log_slave_updates   = 1
#auto-increment-increment = 2
#auto-increment-offset = 1

## Global Buffer memory utilization equation:
# innodb_buffer_pool_size + innodb_additional_mem_pool_size + innodb_log_buffer_size + key_buffer_size + query_cache_size
long_query_time = 3
innodb_checksum_algorithm=NONE
interactive_timeout = 300
wait_timeout = 40
myisam_repair_threads = 8
myisam-block-size = 8096
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = off
innodb_use_sys_malloc
innodb_sync_array_size = 4
innodb_read_ahead_threshold = 56
innodb_purge_threads = 4
innodb_adaptive_flushing = off
innodb_use_native_aio = off
innodb_random_read_ahead
optimizer_search_depth = 24
table_definition_cache = 400
table_open_cache = 2048
delay-key-write = ALL
innodb_checksum_algorithm = innodb
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
thread_pool_size = 16
thread_handling = pool-of-threads

innodb_disable_sort_file_cache
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 32
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = off

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 128M
```

I have multiple hosts connecting to the server and initiating queries. The problem I am facing is that randomly the DB server stops accepting connections. All connections start piling up and in around 3 or 5 seconds it comes back to normal. When I run `show processlist` I see a lot of connections piled up waiting on to be `connected` but since the DB server stops accepting connections, eventually the connection pool becomes full, no further connections are allowed.

During this blackout period, I am not able to see what's going on the DB server because i just won't give me any info even if the connection is established already. `iostat -d -x 1` won't show anything unusual with the disks, CPU is also mostly idle. TCP connections piles up since the clients wants to open connections because they need to push data.

I am not able to figure out what's wrong here. Is this something specific to my DB, or the machine or the config. I need some help here on where and what to look for to identify and rectify the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This questions might be better for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems fairly obviously related to thread pooling... If you enable the `--extra-port` option you should be able to make an administrative connection that's immune to the stall. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/thread-pool-in-mariadb/

Answer (score 0):

> thread_stack            = 512K    #default: 32bit: 192K, 64bit: 256K

I have not heard of needing more than 256K.  Did you discover a need for 512K?  Together with

> max_connections = 900

You potentially need 500MB for processes.  (Granted, this is not a big deal since you have 128GB of ram.)

Back to the problem...

Turn on the slow_log with long_query_time = 1.  After the next occurrence, run pt-query-digest against the slowlog.  There may be some surprises there.  Note that queries hung across the 3-5 second pause will register as taking several seconds, even if they should take only milliseconds.  There's still a risk that it won't point the finger at the real cause of the Pause.